# Can anyone summarize the noticeable difference between list, tuple, dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

A little bit confusion about some data structure in Python.

Could any expert give some rules of thumb in order to help me get out of this mess?

Comment: What exactly about them confuses you so?

Comment: I'm not sure what mess you refer to. This question isn't concrete enough for SO, IMHO. Please ask a more specific question

Comment: that would be....When to use each of them?

Comment: This is like asking the difference between a truck/boat/airplane

Comment: If you just escaped from growing up in the jungle, you might very well want to know the difference between a truck, a boat and an airplane. I see nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: Since Python has numerous tutorials online, a vague question like this is very, very difficult to answer.  Which tutorial lead to the "mess"?  What is the "mess"?  There's no point in repeating a tutorial here.  What's important is identifying specific issues and responding to those issues.  The "truck goes on land" part seems hardly worth repeating here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take on the most important concepts regarding list/tuple/dict:

**List** - When you have a collection of items and may want to add/remove items, rearrange their order, and so on.

**Tuple** - When you have a collection of items and do NOT want to add/remove items, or rearrange their order. Realizing the usefulness of this comes with experience.

**Dictionary** - When you want to map certain keys to certain values, like a dictionary of words. The typical use case is when you have some kind of identifier (the `key`) such as a person's name:

```
>>> addresses = {}
>>> addresses['john'] = 'somewhere' # Set john's address
>>> print "John's address is", addresses['john'] # Retrieve it
```

Answer (score 8):

They are all covered in:

[Python - Data Structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

- List - when you have data that has some order
- Tuple - when ordered data is to be immutable
- Dictionary - when data is related by key - value pairs